# What Java-Web-Framework to use if JSF is oversized?

Tags: java, web-applications, jsf

we think about to move a project from PHP to Java. It's a small web application with about 5 pages. We have JSF-experience, but i think JSF will be oversized and too cumbersome (we will massivly make use of JS).
What can you recommend? GWT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at Wicket: http://wicket.apache.org/

Comment: Hello Adriaan, it might be interesting for you that we followed your advice and will use Wicket for that.
Thank you.

Comment: Good to hear! It's a great platform, isn't it? Currently I am using Wicket again for a new startup company I am involved with. Good luck with your endeavours.

Answer (score 3):

check out the ZK framework

Answer (score 2):

If the web is so small, you can use servlets + JSP.  I would choose Spring if you have previous experience with it.

I do not recommend GWT if your page is going to make extensive use of Javascript as, in my opinion, simple event handling works fine but it limits what you can do with JS.

Comment: Thank you about your estimation of GWT, that was helpful

Answer (score 1):

5 pages call for nothing else but plain JSP + Servlets.

Comment: I will think about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends what sophisticated are these 5 pages. The simplest (maybe not quickest) solution is write in plain Servlets/JSP. If you decide use a framework you can choose between:

- [Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/)
- [Stripes](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/)

If you want to create quick running prototype use without initial configuration problem, try:

- [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo)
- [Play!](http://www.playframework.org/)
- [Grails](http://www.grails.org/) - this is Groovy framework

Comment: Thank you - I'd prefer to have more control over the html output, so i think something like Play! is the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Play! Framework. This is by far the easiest one to use. Been a user of Apache Turbine (since 2002), Apache Struts, CakePHP, I finally landed on Play!. You can watch a 10 mins video on http://www.playframework.org/ but here I would like to mention some of my gotchas:

1. Easy, actually too easy to use. I read some comments says 5 pages call for nothing else but JSP+Servlets. I would say that's too heavy. You will find yourself missed in those xml configuations. With play you need nearly no configuration to land off.
2. Scalable. Because of the stateless model, the only thing you need to do to scale your 5 page hello world web app into a million vists per day busy site is to increase your box and running more instance of your app. You don't need to change one line of code to reach there.
3. Performance. Check [this](http://www.jtict.com/blog/rails-wicket-grails-play-lift-jsp/) to see how Play! outperforms it's competitors when you use it as a standalone http server
4. Very active community and very good contributors. The questions you post on Play's google group get answered promptly. And you can find many interesting stuff contributed by community at [here](http://www.playframework.org/modules)